# Google App Engine keeps deleting my local database

Tags: google-app-engine

After I've stop using Google App Engine on my local database for testing, I will come back a few days later and it has removed/deleted my local datastore.

How can I get it to stop doing this?  I have a large data set locally that I use for testing before deploying it and I don't want to recreate this every time I go to work on something.

There is a checkbox in the Settings called "clear datastore on launch:, but this is unchecked.

I am using the python backend.  Where is the local datastore stored?  Is it in some tmp directory that keeps getting cleared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local datastore is stored in your system's temporary directory by default. You can supply the `--datastore_path` command to specify an alternate location for the datastore.

Note that it's generally a good idea to do your development in a way that doesn't rely on the contents of the local datastore remaining long-term - writing a script that loads a known test dataset is usually a good idea.